# Matlab: raster 3d objects but vector axes

Tags: matlab, eps, rasterize

I have a 3D isosurface in matlab that I need to attach to a LaTeX file and im saving it with `-depsc`. To my knowledge, I can either save it with `-painters`, which produces a pure vector file or `-opengl` which rasters the whole figure. My problem is the vector file is too large (~100MB), but I need the axes and fonts to be vectorial so I can replace them in LaTeX via psfrag. Is there a way in MATLAB to raster the 3D objects but keep the axis and fonts as vector graphics?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 100MB figure file seems large. I'd be surprised if you can actually see a lot of the data points on the plot with a normal resolution screen. One idea would be to downsample you plot so that their are fewer points being saved. Without an actual example in your question it's hard to elaborate on this suggestion...

Comment: @Wolfie vector file formats get often that big, specially when they need to represent non-vector information

Comment: @AnderBiguri: PS (and consequently EPS and PDF) as well as SVG can combine raster and vector drawings.

Comment: @CrisLuengo hum, perhaps then its the matlab "save to eps" thingie, but in the past I tried to do this from MATLAB and if there was an image in the eps, the file size would go crazy, assuming because it was triying to vector-describe the pixel image

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Yes, MATLAB outputs either raster or vector, it cannot combine the two. But it's not the file format that limits it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo ah, my bad! Lesson leaned :D thanks

Comment: @Menc MATLAB has some TeX and LaTeX capabilities. Can't you do what you need directly in MATLAB and thus avoid psfrag?

Comment: Have you looked at: [vecrast](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/64650-vecrast)

Comment: Haven't tried it, but what about `export_fig` ?

Comment: @LuisMendo That was what I was doing. But still it's not the same having a raster version of the labels than actual text.

Comment: @obchardon This is exactly what I needed, thanks.